# Libgdx change color of Texture at runtime

Tags: 2d, textures, libgdx

[I've also asked this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034352/libgdx-change-color-of-texture-at-runtime).

In a Libgdx game, I have some `Animation`s for my `Player`. All the `Frame`s for this `Animation` are inside a `TextureAtlas`. The `Player` `Texture`s show a human, with a white T-Shirt. The T-Shirt is the only white part of the `Player`.
Now i want to be able to replace the white color with red for `Player`1, with green for `Player`2 and so on. How can I do that, without losing the advantage of the `TextureAtlas` (`Texture` switching)?

Of course 1 way would be to store 4 versions of every `Frame`, for 4 different `Players` (colors). However, there are games out there where you can fully customize the `Player`, give them a blue hat, red pants, and pink shirts and so on. How can this be done?

Comment: There are a bunch of answers for this [on the StackOverflow original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034352/libgdx-change-color-of-texture-at-runtime) already. Could you [flag it with a moderator to get it migrated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)?

Comment: This question has already been asked on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Please don't cross post. If you think the question belongs here, have it moved here, don't ask it again here.

Comment: @Byte56 oh sorry i did not know that thats possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a white texture for the t-shirt. When you draw, change the color of the batch to the color you want for t-shirt. After you draw, change the color of the batch to the original.

I assume you have separate parts for your player and not one texture for the entire player. Parts meaning head, arms, legs, neck, body..etc. That's how other games you mentioned should do it.

Comment: I planed to have one texture for the whole player, wouldn't it be hard to have a working `Animation`, if all parts are separated?

Comment: No, it won't be hard at all.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. So i would have 1 `Texture` in the `TextureAtlas`, which is only the T-Shirt, in a white color and the i set the color of the `SpriteBatch` before drawing the T-Shirt and the i reset it to the standard color right?

Comment: Yes..that sounds correct.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! Is there no easier way with only one `Texture`, if i only want to customize the T-Shirt?

Comment: You can use pixmap. Search for libgdx pixmap.

Comment: Yea i know this way, but then i would loose the `TextureAtlas` advantage cause i need to create a new `Texture` out of the one i have right?

Comment: That's true..just create separate body parts..